# Seeming extremely simple spreadsheet or app for math & computer challenged person

Tags: finance

A friend is challenged by math, pretty much even arithmetic (but can use a calculator). They can use Excel, especially if I tweak it initially for budget categories.

I am looking for an Excel sheet or Android app where every bit of expenditure is entered, as it happens. At the end of the month, it should show where the money went, by category, including any savings or loss. And annual summary would be nice too, especially for stuff that doesn't happen every month.

Extras, like "you spent a lot more on X this month" are welcome, but not at the cost of simplicity of use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going by old memories combined with the current website, but I think [GnuCash](https://www.gnucash.org) meets your [requirements](https://www.gnucash.org/features.phtml):

- You can enter all expenditures as they happen
- At the end of every month, it can show where money went, by category
- Annual summary is available

As a nice bonus, it is cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows).

Whether or not it is simple enough will be subjective.  The GUI is simple, and if one does not dive in too deep, I recall it being easy to use.  You'll probably want to set it up for your friend.

An easy way to try it on Windows is to use the [PortableApps version](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/gnucash_portable).